# I'm running Ubuntu on my Nexus 7, do I have access to the same packages as if I'm running Ubuntu on my Desktop?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I noticed that some packages are not available on my Nexus 7 when browsing the Software Center or using "apt-cache search". Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 3):

No Not Exactly, The Nexus 7 is an ARM based platform, therefore uses a different package archive than your common x86 Desktop. If the desired package is not available for ARM, then it will not be available to download.

As there are some Nexus 7 specific packages. These packages are found in the nexus 7 ppa (ppa:ubuntu-nexus7/ppa).  The Nexus 7 PPA is enabled by default when you install. We are currently in the process of migrating all our changes upstream into Raring Ringtail (13.04). When that switch occurs, most updates will come from the main Raring repositories.

Comment: The question is asking why there are certain packages in main/universe that aren't showing up, not about nexus 7 specific packages.

Answer (score 3):

The nexus 7 uses an arm CPU. Anything that doesn't work on an arm CPU will not be available.

Comment: And it uses the armhf architecture, which is the only supported one in Raring, so technically things would need to be compiled for armhf.